# Problema de puntero a estructura

Tags: c++, punteros

Tengo un problema, lo que pasa es que declaro una estructura llamada `struct Alumno` y creo un arreglo de la estructura llamado `alumnos[3]`, tambien creo un puntero `*p=alumnos` que apunta a la primera dirección de el arreglo.

En la función principal creo un bucle para recorrer este arreglo y así llenarlo.

Después quiero imprimir a un dato `cout<<(p+2)->nombre;` pero no me imprime nada, parece que no guardé bien los datos en el arreglo, pero ***¿cual es el problema?***

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Alumno{
    char nombre[20];
    int edad;
    int promedio;
}alumnos[3],*p=alumnos;

int main(){

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del alumno: "; cin.getline(p->nombre,20,'\n');
        cout<<"Ingrese la edad: "; cin>>p->edad;
        cout<<"Ingrese el promedio de "<<p->nombre<<" : ";cin>>p->promedio;
        fflush(stdin);
        cout<<endl;
        p++;
    }

    cout<<(p+2)->nombre;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veamos tu bucle:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    ...
    p++;
}
```

En cada *pasada*, incrementas el puntero `p`; por lo que al finalizar, `p` apunta a `p + 2`.

Luego, haces

```
cout<<(p+2)->nombre;
```

Recordemos que p **ya estaba incrementado**, por lo que eso equivale a

```
count << ( p + 4 )->nombre
```

Simplemente, elimina ese último incremente, fuera de tu bucle:

```
cout<<( p->nombre );
```

con lo que te mostrará **el último** elemento de tu formación `alumnos`.